# DWG to SHP - suddenly a huge ammount of data in one file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, autocad, dwg

I converted four DWG-Files with ArcMap to SHP. 
Suddenly one data had a huge ammount of data:

file 1: DWG: 4,5 MB ---->   SHP. 9,7 MB

file 2: DWG: 12,7 MB --> SHP: 110 MB (!)

file 3: DWG: 3,4 MB ---->   SHP: 10,3 MB

file 4: DWG: 6,3 MB ---->   SHP: 13,5 MB

First I had Adobe Illustrator-files and converted them to DWG. What can I do against this problem and reduce the ammount of data? After the first convert from Ai to DWG it was not a problem.

Comment: dBase is a fixed-width format.  Lots of fields with lots of rows == big files

Comment: I think your problem is because first convert from Ai to DWG format, I couldn't find specific solution for your question but I suppose firstly you should fix DWG files by AutoCAD and thent convert to SHP format again, this below link might be helpful, https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/AutoCAD-DWG-files-unexpectedly-increase-in-file-size.html